# Почему скрипт не работает? Vector 3

Tags: unity3d

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Slime : MonoBehaviour
{

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        GameObject Archer = GameObject.FindWithTag("Archer");
        Transform bober = Archer.transform;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float distance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, bober.position);
        Debug.Log(distance);

    }
}
```

Comment: Одно из самых отстойнейших описаний проблемы за историю ruSO

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

`Transform bober` надо бхявить как свойство класса, а в методе `Start` писать уже просто:

```
bober = Archer.transform;
```

В ином случае получается, что ты объявляешь переменную в одном методе, а использовать пытаешься в другом